# Calculate how many slides

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate how many slides in a slideshow.

in JS:

```
var slides = $('document.getElementById("slide").getAttribute("data-slide").slide-new');
```

And in My HTML

```
<div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="0" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div id="slideshow" >
        <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
        <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
        <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div id="slideshow" >
        <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
        <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
        <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
        <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to calculate How Many "Slide-new" there is "slide" variable.
In 'slides' variable I want 3 for first slideshow and 4 for second slideshow. But I can't get it...

Thanks

Comment: Use classes to group your div. Not ID.

Answer (score 0):

Assign class name to get the count of the class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideCount = $('[data-slide]').length;
  for (i = 1; i <= slideCount; i++) {
    var t = $('#slide' + i + ' #slideshow').children().attr('class');
    $("#text" + i).html(i + 'st Slide has' + $("." + t).length + 'slides' + '<br/>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="0" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
    <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
    <div class="slide-new">Some Text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide" id="slide2" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slide-new1">Some Text</div>
    <div class="slide-new1">Some Text</div>
    <div class="slide-new1">Some Text</div>
    <div class="slide-new1">Some Text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<span id="text1"></span>
<span id="text2"></span>
```

[**Click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdY62/1/)

Here is the update:

[**Update**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdY62/5/)

Comment: I want to calculate How Many "Slide-new" there in "slide" variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('.slide').each(function(){
  var slides = $(this).find('.slide-new').length
  alert(slides);
});
```

Note: don't use same id more than one time in a page.